# jquery daterangepicker: bind to an ajax success element

Tags: daterangepicker

How to rebind the daterangepicker to an HTML element which arose from an ajax success call? I tried lot of ways but none of it is working. Essentially I am invoking an ajax call to load a html content and then attempting to bind daterangepicker to it, but its not working. Can someone please help me.